# Sublime text 2 snippets

Tags: python, sublimetext2

Is there any way to access current scope (class name or function name) inside a snippet? I am trying to write a snippet for `super(CurrentClassName, self).get(*args, **kwargs)` but seems like I can't really replace `CurrentClassName` with actual class name. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: no, you'd have to do this via a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry snippets are primarily meant for reusability; you can do precisely as you say above but cannot insert specific things - you would have to write your own plugin in order to add this functionality as it would require things like a specific way of selecting things to modify and replace which would be specific to it.

Answer (score 0):

For future Googlers, someone has made such a plugin:

https://github.com/rubyruy/SuperPython